# Adding F_ZLEV and T_ZLEV to road network - do I make all ground roads 0?

Tags: network-analyst, elevation

I am trying to create a network dataset from TIGER for a very small city. Of course there is no elevation/Z data. I am watching a tutorial that shows how to add Z values (1 for bridge, 0 for ground, -1 for tunnel). They go in detail on how to treat highway ramps, but they do not say if I should do a calculate field for all "ground" roads to set them to 0. Currently they are blank/null. Using ArcMap 10.4 Network Analyst.

TLDR; should I "calculate field" for all of my ground roads to be equal to 0?

Comment: I don't know which classification system you are using but, generally, you should try to avoid null values in public data - it makes it look like you are missing data. If you know they are ground roads: you should classify them as ground roads (0) in my opinion. Null should be for unknown road types.

Comment: I am not going to be providing this data to the public. Thanks for your input, I guess I will go ahead and code any nulls as "0". It's an area of 10 sq miles with a few highway overpasses that I have manually coded to 1 to signify a bridge. So I didn't know if all other streets needed to be "0". Seems like it can't hurt. Thanks!